# Sum of indicator functions of binomial random variables

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions

Let $x_1, x_2,..., x_m$ be iid binomial random variables (each with a number of trials n and probability of success in each trial p). Define a list of binary indicator variables $y_1,y_2,...,y_m$ for at least $K$ successes  i.e.,

$ y_i = 
    \begin{cases}
      1 & \text{if } x_i\geq K\\
      0 & \text{else}
    \end{cases}$

What is the variance of $z=\sum_1^m y_i$ ?

Answer (score 2):

We have $Var\,z=m\,Var\,y_1$,
$$Var\,y_1=P(x_1\ge K)(1-P(x_1\ge K))=P(x_1\ge K)P(x_1<K))=(1-F(K-1))F(K-1)
=(1-I_{1-p}(n-K+1,K))I_{1-p}(n-K+1,K)$$
according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function), where $F$ is the cdf of the binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, and $I_\cdot(\cdot,\cdot)$ is the regularized incomplete beta function. Thus,
$$Var\,z=m\,(1-I_{1-p}(n-K+1,K))I_{1-p}(n-K+1,K).$$